# Youtube API playVideo doesn't work when running locally

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Anyone had instance where onYouTubeplayerReady works, i.e. id is passed, but the object isn't working?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
<script language="javascript">
var vid;
function onYouTubePlayerReady(id) {
    vid = id;
}
        var currWidth = 320, currHeight = 265;
$("#ytplayer").html($.flash.create({
            "swf":"http://www.youtube.com/v/BA7fdSkp8ds?fs=1&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer",
            "width": currWidth,
            "height": currHeight,
            "params":{ allowScriptAccess: "always" }
                                }));
function play() {
    var vobj;
    if (vid) {
        vobj = document.getElementById(vid);
        vobj.playVideo();
    }
}
</script>
<div onClick="play()">Play</div>
```

The vid is correctly captured, but when I click "Play" it says playVideo is not a function. I've read earlier posts about Internet issue. My case is in Intranet so I assume it should be fine? Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's written on the API page:

> Getting Started Note: To test any of these calls, you must have your
>   file running on a webserver, as the Flash player restricts calls
>   between local files and the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the intranet part is your problem, you need to upload the files to a web server. See http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted